# Xamarin Android Lib Bindings Glide ClassCast exception

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-glide

I have an Android library that uses Glide for image loading. 
Glide generates few classes such as **GlideApp**, **GlideRequests**, etc.
In my library Glide used with:

```
GlideApp.with(view)...
```

In **with** method of the generated GlideApp class is such code:

```
 public static GlideRequests with(View view) {
    return (GlideRequests) Glide.with(view);
 }
```

Where **GlideRequests** is also generated by Glide class.

I created Xamarin bindings for my aar library, and also included Glide bindings from NuGet. But when **GlideApp.with(view)...** method is called inside library code Xamarin gives me an exception:

```
Java.Lang.ClassCastException: com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager cannot be cast to 
  com.photobutler.android.pbsdk.presentation.glide.GlideRequests
  at java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager cannot be 
  cast to com.photobutler.android.pbsdk.presentation.glide.GlideRequests
  at at com.photobutler.android.pbsdk.presentation.glide.GlideApp.with(...)
```

**GlideRequests** is a subclass of **RequestManager**

```
public class GlideRequests extends RequestManager {...}
```

So everything should be fine, but I got that exception. Could anyone please help me find a solution for that?

Comment: [Are you using proguard?](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2683)

Comment: @JoeLv Yeah, that was the issue for this. Could u add an answer with that link and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Maybe it is the proguard problem.](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2683)